# Do two instances of the same Java app reference the same memory location of a non-primitive type?

Tags: java

I understand that an object copied from another object which is instantiated from a reference type (non-primitive type) has the same value and that updating a value of one object results in updating the other.

Do two instances (ie. executing `java com.example.MyApp` twice in parallel) of the application running at the same time have the same effect (ie. 2 instances of the same app reference and update the same value)?

I have very small test code that finishes running very quickly so I cannot tell how it works.

Comment: No. Each instance of the JVM is independent. Assuming you are running the app, and not compiling it. Although two compiler instances would also be independent. I think. Not sure why you would want that.

Comment: Yes, running the app. Thanks @elliott-frisch